# How can I make hyperlinks in popup windows clickable in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, popupwindow

I have an Android App, which opens some popup window. But Hyperlinks in popup window are not clickable. I tried some methods such:
in activity_main.xml

```
    <TextView
`.....`
`android:autoLink="web"`
`android:autoLink="all"`
```

I think the problem is because my text is in popup window.
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView dataList = findViewById(R.id.dataList);

        dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                BlackBoardEntry entry = (BlackBoardEntry) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String content = entry.getContent();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_popup, null, false);
                ((TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.contentView)).setText(content);

                PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, 500, 1000, true);
                popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


                }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<BlackBoardEntry> entries = BlackBoardClient.getBlackBoardEntries();
                    BlackBoardAdapter adapter = new BlackBoardAdapter(entries, getApplicationContext());
                    dataList.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

it looks like this:
[image: the popup windows that open when you click at some topic]

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void createClickableSpanText(ClickableSpan listener, TextView textView, String message, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(message);
        spannableString.setSpan(listener, startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannableString);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
```

you can do something like the above to set a "clickable span" to the text between startIndex and endIndex. This should allow you to click that certain piece of text.